# Failure in openssl EVP_DigestUpdate() function

Tags: c++, c, encryption, openssl, aix

I'm facing intermittent core dump on a utility which is calling EVP_DigestUpdate() function of openssl library. please note I'm observing this failure in AIX operating system. I have attached the call trace and point where the failure is happening, I'm unable to reproduce this every time and therefore unable to debug the same. Also please note that the utility is called in a multiprocess fashion, which means at a instant there are at least 4 instance of utility are running in which one of them fails.

```
*Function Trace:
IOT/Abort trap in pthread_kill at 0x900000000582f94
[untrusted: /usr/lib/libpthreads.a(shr_xpg5_64.o)]
0x900000000582f94 (pthread_kill+0x194) e8a20028             ld   r5,0x28(r2)
(dbx) where
pthread_kill(??, ??) at 0x900000000582f94 [untrusted: /usr/lib/libpthreads.a(shr_xpg5_64.o)]
_p_raise(??) at 0x9000000005827e4 [untrusted: /usr/lib/libpthreads.a(shr_xpg5_64.o)]
setpgrp() at 0x900000000039268 [untrusted: /usr/lib/libc.a(shr_64.o)]
monldq(??) at 0x900000000055c64 [untrusted: /usr/lib/libc.a(shr_64.o)]
.() at 0x1005e20d0 [inaccessible: missing <username>]
.() at 0x10288f8c0 [inaccessible: missing <username>]
.() at 0x10288f290 [inaccessible: missing <username>]
.() at 0x102e59b48 [inaccessible: missing <username>]
sha256_block_p8(??, ??, ??) at 0x80000000049e2a0
sha256_block_data_order() at 0x80000000049b93c
SHA256_Update@AF12_4() at 0x8000000004c51f0
update256() at 0x8000000004c3bd0
EVP_DigestUpdate() at 0x8000000004bcc84
OpenSSLCrypto::updateHash(void*,const SecureArray&)(0x112ba6290, 0xffffffffffefc50, 
0x112ba63f0, 0xffffffffffefc10) at 0x80000000043d77c.
<There are few calls from utility before this>*
```

I'm unable to understand what is causing the failure, and why it is intermittent?

Comment: Build your program with debug information if that's not already the case. Use the debugger to check the data you pass to the OpenSSL functions. An intermittent error may be caused by a memory access problem. I don't know what tools are available to debug such problems on AIX. If you can build and run your program on Linux you could use `valgrind`.

Comment: More than likely one of the parameters you've supplied to `updateHash` is not properly sized and/or initialized. Note that such bugs may not always result in a crash, it depends on what happens afterward. And yes, `valgrind` is your friend.

Comment: Electric Fence sometimes helps finding the bugs, but it is also easier to use on Linux than on Aix. (Also compiling+running the program on a different platform with a different compiler might point out weak points; e.g. reading from address zero is possible on Aix but not possible in Linux.)

Comment: I'm able to hit this issue locally, only when the enviroment variable OPENSSL_ppccap is set to value 4,  when value is not set to 4 sha256_block_ppc(??, ??, ??) is called and when the it is set to 4 sha256_block_p8(??, ??, ??) is called, is it related to something that p8 function cannot be called on particular architecture?